# virtual machine not accessible by putty or ssh (port 22: Connection refused)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtual-machine

I have installed ubuntu on VMware® Workstation 14 Player.

I can see the ip with ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:65:af:66  
          inet addr:192.168.223.129  Bcast:192.168.223.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe65:af66/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:337 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:362 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:40108 (40.1 KB)  TX bytes:34591 (34.5 KB)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0x2000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:686 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:686 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:54536 (54.5 KB)  TX bytes:54536 (54.5 KB)
```

When I try to connect by ssh or putty It is not connecting and returning message:

```
ssh 192.168.223.129
ssh: connect to host 192.168.223.129 port 22: Connection refused
```

Comment: Are you sure that the sshd is installed and running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install ssh server on your ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Now start and enable the debian ssh server to start at system reboot.

```
systemctl start ssh.service

systemctl enable ssh.service
```

Also run netstat command to make sure that ssh port 22 is open and running.

```
netstat -tulnp | grep 22
```

then try to access...